# Why the constructor property of object created by Factory function is different from Constructor function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The object created with constructor function prints the name of function but when I repeat the process with objects of factory function they print,
**ƒ Object() { [native code] }**
instead of printing the name of function as in the case of constructor function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). We can't help you with code we can't see! Show us both of the things you're asking about, the output you're seeing from them, and what difference you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you're asking about why using `new` with a function creates an object whose `constructor` property refers back to that function, but when you use a factory function that creates the object with an object literal, it doesn't:

```js
function Example(x) {
    this.x = x;
}

function makeExample(x) {
    return {
        x: x
    };
}

var e1 = new Example(42);
var e2 = makeExample(42);

console.log("e1:");
console.log(e1.constructor === Example); // true
console.log(e1.constructor);             // (Some version of the Example function)
console.log("e2:");
console.log(e2.constructor === Example); // false
console.log(e2.constructor);             // "function Object() { [native code] }"
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

The reason is that when you use `new Example`, the object that gets created uses `Example.prototype` as its prototype:

```js
function Example() {
}
var e = new Example();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(e) === Example.prototype); // true
```

Which looks something like this in memory:

```
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                    |                                  |
                    v                                  |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                         |
Example−−−>|   (function)    |                         |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                         |
           | name: "Example" |                         |
           | prototype       |−−−+                     |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |                     |
                                 |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−>|  (object)   |   |
e1−−−−−−−−>|     (object)    |   |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |   | constructor |−−−+
           | [[Prototype]]   |−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
           | ...             |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

In contrast, when you create an object with an object literal, its prototype is assigned from `Object.prototype`:

```js
var e = {};
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(e) === Object.prototype); // true
```

which looks something like this in memory (exactly the same, just with `Object` instead of `Example`):

```
                    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                    |                                  |
                    v                                  |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                         |
Object−−−−>|   (function)    |                         |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                         |
           | name: "Object"  |                         |
           | prototype       |−−−+                     |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |                     |
                                 |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−>|  (object)   |   |
e2−−−−−−−−>|     (object)    |   |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |   | constructor |−−−+
           | [[Prototype]]   |−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
           | ...             |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Even though you do that in a factory function (like `makeExample` earlier), there's no ongoing connection between the function and the object it created, because it was created via an object literal, which just connects the object to the `Object` constructor.

So where does the `constructor` property come from?

The object assigned to the `prototype` property on most functions when the functions are created has a `constructor` property on it that refers to the function:

```js
function Example() {
}
console.log(Example.prototype.constructor === Example); // true
```

So objects that use that object as their prototype inherit that `constructor` property. So with

```
function Example(x) {
    this.x = x;
}

var e1 = new Example(42);
console.log(e1.constructor);
```

`e1`'s prototype is the object on `Example.prototype`, which has a `constructor` property referring to `Example`, so that's what gets output. But with

```
function makeExample(x) {
    return {
        x: x
    };
}

var e2 = makeExample(42);
```

the object was created with an object literal, so it has `Object.prototype` as its prototype, and `Object.prototype.constructor` is `Object`.